# Can I use module#prepend instead of alias_method_chain to monkey patch this concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching, alias-method-chain

I am patching a [concern in the Devise Token Auth gem](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/c11dd18c4cc9a78ab60cd668f06cfd5b2d13e4ec/app/models/devise_token_auth/concerns/user.rb#L216).

I have it working with `alias_method_chain` but am wondering if I can use `module#prepend` instead in this scenario?

Note: We are on ruby 2.2.x

Existing:

```
DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User.module_eval do
  def token_validation_response_with_customer_info
    json = token_validation_response_without_customer_info
    # add some customer stuff based on has_role? check
    json
  end

  alias_method_chain :token_validation_response, :customer_info
end
```

Comment: I don't have `ActiveSupport` installed, otherwise I would do it myself, but … why don't you just do it and see if it works?

Comment: I ran into this "alias_method_chain" issue while trying to use Devise as well. Did you ever try to patch it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User.prepend(
  Module.new do
    def token_validation_response
      json = super
      # add some customer stuff based on has_role? check
      json
    end
  end
)
```